# Decided to try my hand with homemade functions in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make a function that gets a string. I successfully made a function called `mult()` which multiplies numbers together. You can find my code right here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE
char *GetString(void);
int main (void)
{
    char *a;
    printf("give me your name please\n");
    a = GetString();
    printf("Why hello their, %s", a);
}
char *GetString(void)
{
    char x;
    fgets(x, MAX_NAME_SIZE, stdin);
}
```

and here are my errors

```
cc     string.c   -o string
string.c.c: In function ‘GetString’:
string.c:15:24: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
 fgets(x, MAX_NAME_SIZE, stdin);
               ^
string.c:15:24: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from string.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:622:14: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern char *fgets (char *__restrict __s, int __n, FILE *__restrict __stream)
      ^
make: *** [string] Error 1
```

---

Solved.
I solved it by changing char x; to char *x and also having GetString return x, also I added a size to MAX_NAME_SIZE.

Comment: You have MANY bugs. you #define a constant, but don't give it any value. you then pass that valueless constant around expecting to to HAVE a value. You have `char *a` to accept your GetString data, but within GetString you only have `char x`. GetString then also doesn't RETURN anything, so your fgets() call is utterly pointless.

Comment: For one thing, GetString() has no return.  For another thing, you need an array to store the string that is inputted.

Comment: "I solved it by changing `char x;` to `char *x`" - waiting for the next question where he asks why it crashes sometimes

Answer (score 1):

You macro `#define` is wrong; try with

```
     #define MAX_NAME_SIZE   1024
```

(or some other number, perhaps 128)

And you should compile with `gcc -Wall -g string.c -o string`; BTW, you could get the preprocessor output with `gcc -C -E string.c`

Answer (score 0):

You must allocate memory for `x`, and then pass it's address (of type `char*`) to `fgets`.  Something like:

```
char* getString(void)
{
    char* s = malloc(MAX_NAME_SIZE);
    if ((s = fgets(s, MAX_NAME_SIZE, stdin)) == NULL)
    {
        free(s);
    }

    return s;
}
```

The caller must now `free()` the memory allocated in `getString()`.

Alternatively you can pass in the string:

```
char* getString(char* s, size_t size)
{
    return fgets(s, size, stdin);
}
```

I would say that there is hardly a reason to have a `getString()` function here.

Comment: `fgets(s,size,stream)` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream, so using `size-1` or allocating `MAX_NAME_SIZE+1` isn't neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is fairly clear - you are passing a char where you should be passing a char*. You could just pass &c, which would fix the compiler error, but would be a really bad idea since you presumably want a name to be more than one character long. That's enough hints for now...